# Does bilinear/bicubic interpolation operate on each color channel independently?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, bicubic, bilinear-interpolation

I'm using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom` with either bilinear interpolation or bicubic interpolation (order=1 or 3, if I'm correct).

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html

When working with an RGB image, do the bilinear/bicubic interpolation algorithms operate independently on each color channel, or is there some dependency between color channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndimage.interpolation.zoom` does not have a concept of RGB channels; it zooms an arbitrary n-dimensional array without any particular meaning to each dimension. For example, if you have an image stored as an array of shape `(20, 20, 3)` then after `zoom(image, 2)` it will become an array of shape `(40, 40, 6)` which is of course undesirable.

Presumably you will use `zoom(image, (2, 2, 1))` to have 2x zoom in both dimensions and no "zoom" in the channel dimension. If so, there is no spillover between channels then. Reading the C code of [`NI_ZoomShift`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b26ac7e173503b34c40e943cf45f32984408f817/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_interpolation.c#L573) I see that zoom is achieved using [`get_spline_interpolation_weights`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b26ac7e173503b34c40e943cf45f32984408f817/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_splines.c#L7) which performs **one-dimensional** spline interpolation (not bilinear or bicubic). This means that the zoom will consist of:

1. Going over every 1D slice `image[:, c, ch]` and zooming it by 1D interpolation (no interaction between slices).
2. Going over every 1D slice `image[r, :, ch]` and zooming it by 1D interpolation.
3. Going over every 1D slice `image[r, c, :]` and zooming it by 1D interpolation - which with zoom factor of 1 will leave the values the same up to machine precision.

A test of the above: zooming the entire image vs zooming each channel separately.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
image = np.random.uniform(size=(20, 20, 3))
output = zoom(image, (2, 2, 1))
for k in range(3):
    output_channel = zoom(image[:, :, k], 2)
    print(np.max(np.abs(output_channel - output[:, :, k])))
```

The printed values are around 1e-15, i.e., the output is the same up to floating point errors.